# setTimeout but for a given time

Tags: javascript, datetime, settimeout

Is there anything readily available in JavaScript (i.e. not through "plugins") that allows me to do something like `setTimeout`, but instead of saying in how many milliseconds something should happen, I give it a date object telling it when to do something?

```
setToHappen(function () {
    alert('Wake up!');
}, new Date("..."));
```

And yes, I know I can do this by simply subtracting `new Date()` with my existing date object (or maybe it's the other way around) to get the amount of milliseconds, but I'd still like to know.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to compute the number of milliseconds between now and your date object:

```
function setToHappen(fn, date){
    return setTimeout(fn, date - Date.now());
}
```

**NB** Please note [@calvin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/781079/1582182): this will not work if the number of milliseconds is greater than `2147483647`.

Comment: don't you have to multiply by 1000 to get the miliseconds?

Comment: @Pim, no you don't. 'getTime()' returns the number of milliseconds between 00:00:00 1/1/1970 and the corresponding date object.

Comment: AH ok, I thought it was in seconds.

Comment: Note that this is "99%" correct. If the system clock changes it won't execute 'fn' at 'd'.

Comment: Not only changing the system clock is a problem. When you send the system in sleep modus fn is executed the amount of sleeping time later.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Works perfect for node.js application. Servers don't go to sleep or have the system clock unintentionally change.

Answer (score 11):

Since people are talking about calculating timeout intervals using `date` objects, it should be noted that [the max value `setTimeout()` will accept for the interval parameter is 2147483647 (2^31 - 1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#maximum_delay_value) as `PRIntervalTime` is a signed 32-bit integer. That comes out to just under 25 days.

Answer (score 9):

No, but you could easily write your own function. Just calculate the diference between now and the given moment in miliseconds and call setTimeout with that.

Something like this:

```
 setToHappen = function(fn, date){
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var diff = date.getTime() - now;
  return setTimeout(fn, diff);
 }
```

EDIT: removed the extra multiplication by 1000, thanks chris for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply subtract `Date.now()` from the date

```js
const myDate = new Date('...');
setTimeout(func, myDate - Date.now());
```