# What's the status of the WebExtensions' background page implementations by browser/OS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, standards, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

In Chrome for Win/Mac/Linux it is possible to have browser addon scripts running before the user launches the browser and after they shut the last browser window. In Chrome this is done by claiming the `background` permission - see the [Chrome extensions API docs on `background`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#background). Other browsers [don't seem to support this permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#bcd:webextensions.manifest.permissions). So my questions:

1. Is this also possible with other browsers (e.g. by using some other permission/API...) and with other operating systems (specifically Android/iOS)?
2. What is the behavior of this feature across different operating systems? (I have tried it with Chrome on Ubuntu and while Chrome does continue running and the script keeps performing its task, it doesn't automatically start in background after restarting the OS - I guess one would have to manually add an autostart script for that)

What I'm trying to accomplish is something similar as to what as been asked here: [Display a Chrome desktop notification every day at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032196/display-a-chrome-desktop-notification-every-day-at-specific-time). But I want to learn about cross-browser-and-OS-compatibility before putting too much effort into it. Also an outlook for what's going to be possible in the near future would be nice. :)

(I am aware that something like this could be done using push notifications, but I would also like my app to work offline, so that's not an option.)

Comment: This feature is not cross-platform as you've already found out.

Comment: @wOxxOm Well I haven't really found out yet. It's just that I only managed to find a way to do it on Chrome for Desktop so far - that doesn't necessarily mean, there is no way to achieve it on other browsers/OSes too. (e.g. Chrome doesn't offer addons on Android, but what about Kiwi - does it enable bg tasks to continue running?)  What I did find out in the mean time, is that this won't be possible on iOS anytime soon :( - see explanation here: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/6jjmbf/will_firefox_for_ios_ever_support_webextensions/

Comment: My point is that since it's not guaranteed to work then you can't rely on it, and instead it might make more sense to write a standalone utility.